# Extending log4net's PatternString with a custom converter via configuration

Tags: configuration, log4net

How do you add custom converters to log4net's [PatternString](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html) via the configuration file?

The SDK documentation hints that this is possible via the fact that [one of the AddConverter methods](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.AddConverter_overload_1.html) says it is used by the configurator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example [here](http://cowarthill.com/blog/index.php/2009/12/23/log4net-patternstring/) that demonstrates this.

```
    <appender name="FileAppender">

      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
        <converter>
            <name value="keyword"/>
            <type value="MyNamespace.MyConverter, MyAssembly"/>
        </converter>
        <conversionPattern value="App[%keyword].log"/>
      </file>

    </appender>
```

Comment: The link is broken